# How to draw a 3D line in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I would like to draw a simple line between 2 Points in a 3D space using octave.

I have tried to use plot3 with two 3D vectors:

```
vec1 = [0 0 0]
vec2 = [100 100 100]
hold on;
plot3(vec1,vec2,"-");
```

But this did not work for me.

I found no pure octave code to draw a line between two points/vectors.

Could u help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Matlab you call [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) with three vectors (or matrices), each specifying the *x*, *y* and *z* coordinates respectively. So:

```
plot3([vec1(1) vec2(1)], [vec1(2) vec2(2)], [vec1(3) vec2(3)], '-')
```

Answer (score 2):

For point A (xa, ya, za) and point B (xb, yb, zb)
Line A to B:

```
vectorx=[xa xb]
vectory=[ya yb]
vectorz=[za zb]
plot3(vectorx,vectory,vectorz)
```